# Installing cuSDR on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: software-defined-radio, rtl-sdr, linux

I've been trying to install cuSDR64 on Ubuntu so as to have a 4-receiver 4-display SDR setup. I found the Windows repository on svn [here](http://svn.tapr.org/repos_sdr_hpsdr/trunk/DL3HVH/cuSDR64/). But, it gives an error ([check this question](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/521/installing-cusdr64-on-windows-7-64-bit)).

The cuSDR home page does mention that it can be built on Linux as well, but when I tried to find the source code, I found nothing.

How do I install/build cuSDR64 on Ubuntu 13.04?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a software builder and packager.  While I don't have any use for cuSDR at the moment, I looked at the svn repository and home page, and did some googling:

- there was no Linux installation documentation that I could find.
- there was no common build scripting in the repository.
- there were no Linux packages prepared.
- there does seem to be discussions about cuSDR on the [mailing list](http://lists.openhpsdr.org/listinfo.cgi/hpsdr-openhpsdr.org), and that would seem to be a good place to ask for help from people who may have done it.
- there is also a [brief packaging discussion](http://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/apache-labs/conversations/topics/503).

Good luck, you'll need it.  ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, and the wishes. I too found only what you could. I need a good luck here, LOTS of it. Anyway you could help me with this then?: http://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/521/installing-cusdr64-on-windows-7-64-bit

Comment: Sorry, no, not a glazier, I know my limits, I don't do Windows.